# R function is well and functioning but I'm not getting the exact results

Tags: r, function, statistics

Ok, first let me define the project I'm working on and what I need as results. I have this data of 332 comma separated value files which is actually the US department of health's statistical data on pollution parameters for nitrate and sulphate pollutants. There are 332 IDs for a list of 332 entities that monitored pollution across all cities and I have to conduct some analysis on it.

So the data table looks something like this:

```
Date (yyyy-mm-dd)    sulphate      nitrate     ID
xxxx-xx-01           some value    some value  5
xxxx-xx-02           some value    some value  5
```

So theres daily data for monitor number 5. Similar is with the rest of the 332 IDs.

Now my job requires me to write a function that displays the number of non-NA values according to each ID. Ok? Which means that if I specify ID 1, then the function will process the data table and provide me with a simple data frame with the ID number and the number of non-NA values for that ID.

Now, my current function performs the fact manner as it should if I specify only one ID. but when I specify a combination of IDs, the function provides me the sum of all IDs specified, that is not what i  want actually.

This is the full function:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332){
file.list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE) ## list of files need to be read
pollutant.data <- data.frame() ## forming an empty data frame
for (i in 1:332){
     pollutant.data <- rbind(pollutant.data, read.csv(files))} ## final data frame
ID <- pollutant.data[which(pollutant.data[,'ID'] %in% id),] ## for the id vector that needs to be specified in the function
good <- complete.cases(pollutant.data)
nobs <- sum(complete.cases(ID)) ## sum of complete data according to ID
return(data.frame(id, nobs = nobs))
}
```

Now when I specify say, id = 1, the function give me the correct result. But when I specify more than 1 ID, like so, c(3,6,4), it provides me with the **addition** of all the three IDs with each row for individual ID, and that is where I'm unable to resolve.

Now, I believe that I need to work on the for loop to specify that sum needs to be found for each ID, I tried inserting the for loop between the **good** and **nobs** vector but still I get the wrong values.

Comment: Thanks for the edit nico. Much appreciated

Comment: This question has been asked on Stack Overflow in different forms over 100 times -- please search "[r] pollutant" for duplicates.

Comment: @josilber mark as duplicate in that case. I haven't seen the question before, so I gave an answer anyways... but if it's a duplicate it should be marked as such

Comment: Well what I did found out through search was all pollutant mean. I never found the function I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the culprit:

```
ID <- pollutant.data[which(pollutant.data[,'ID'] %in% id),]
```

You are asking for all of the IDs that match the vector you pass, so you are in no way separating by ID.

A leaner way to do it is:

```
# Generate a mock dataset
test.data <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:5, each = 10), value = rnorm(50))
# Every 5th element is NA
test.data$value[seq(1, 50, 5)] <- NA

countComplete <- function(data.frame, id)
  {
  # Get only the subset of data we need (only requested id)
  tmp <- subset(data.frame, ID %in% id)

  # Split it by ID
  tmp.split <- split(tmp, tmp$ID)

  # Use sapply to count complete cases for the different IDs
  res <- sapply(tmp.split, function(x){
    sum(complete.cases(x))
    })

  # Return the result
  res
  }
```

For instance:

```
countComplete(test.data, c(1,3))
```

Returns

```
1  3 
8  8
```